# Magento2: Why does the Compare Products sidebar on category pages not show up, but return when I delete a certain layout file? See further explanation

Tags: magento2, category, sidebar, compare

The Compare Products sidebar on category pages does not show up, and I was trying to figure out why. So I temporarily deleted files under the `app/design/frontend/customer-name/default` folder to see if it would come back (with help of version control to restore them).
I discovered that when I temporarily delete the file in `app/design/frontend/customer-name/default/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`, the Compare Products sidebar on category pages returns.

When I try to re-add this file with only boilerplate layout xml code, it disappears again.
Adding a layout xml file with only boilerplate code should not change anything, right? Here is that file before I delete it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/listing.css" />
        <css src="css/brand.css" />
        <link src="Magento_Catalog::js/body-class-tag-brand-modify.js" />
        <link src="js/category.js" />
    </head>
<body>
        <referenceContainer name="content" >
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="this.is.a.brand" template="Magento_Catalog::category/brand_tag_class.phtml"/>
           <block class="CompanyName\CategoryPage\Block\FeaturedInCategory" name="category.products.list.no.toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list_without_toolbar.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="category.image" destination="columns.top" before="page.main.title"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Here is the file when I re-add with only boilerplate layout xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Discovered a solution. The boilerplate was wrong. 
The difference is the value of page `layout="2columns-left"` in the 2nd line, instead of page `layout="1column"`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/listing.css" />
        <css src="css/brand.css" />
        <link src="Magento_Catalog::js/body-class-tag-brand-modify.js" />
        <link src="js/category.js" />
    </head>
<body>
        <referenceContainer name="content" >
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="this.is.a.brand" template="Magento_Catalog::category/brand_tag_class.phtml"/>
           <block class="CompanyName\CategoryPage\Block\FeaturedInCategory" name="category.products.list.no.toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list_without_toolbar.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="category.image" destination="columns.top" before="page.main.title"/>
    </body>
</page>
```